# How can I loop this code in python

Tags: python, loops

```
EmailAddress= input("What is your Email?")
import re
def Find (codePattern, Email):
    match = re.search(codePattern,Email)
    if match: print ('Valid Email Address' , match.group())
    else: print ('Invalid Email Address')

Find ('^\w+@+\w+\.+\w+', EmailAddress)
```

how can I loop it so that it asks for another email IF the email is not valid

Comment: simple is use break in `if` and else continue in a infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you refactor your code a bit:

```
def check_email(email, pattern='^\w+@+\w+\.+\w+'):
    return re.search(pattern, email)

email = input("What is your Email?")
while not check_email(email):
    print("Invalid, please try again.")
    email = input("What is your Email?")
```

Comment: I think no need to use bool(), Search [Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern;](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) So `def check_email(__, __): return re.search(pattern, email)`